# Concatenate Letter And Number in Excel - Syntax Confusion

Tags: excel, excel-formula, syntax

Hope someone has some experience with the following issue I have on excel:

Imagine that I'd like to get a value from cell Ai, however I want to consider "i" as input from another cell in the workbook. To make it more concrete, if "i" was a fixed number like 5, then "=A5" operation would work. In my case, I want this number 5 to be dynamic, I wonder if someone know the method.

Answer (score 3):

Use INDEX:

```
=INDEX(A:A,Z1)
```

Where Z1 is the cell in which you put the row number.

Comment: You cannot imagine how long I was looking for this answer, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Using `INDIRECT`:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&B1)
```

where ***B1*** contains row number.